# Attempt to read property "doc" on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `candidat`, and `document` Models but when I use $candidat->document->doc I get Attempt to read property "doc" on null

`Document Model` :

```
 class Document extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'documents';
protected $fillable = [
    'id_candidat',
    'doc',
    'date_depot'];

public function candidat()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(candidat::class, 'candidat_id');
}
}
```

`Candidat Model` :

```
  class candidat extends Model
{
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'candidats';
protected $fillable = [
    'nom',
    'prenom',
    'email',
    'adresse',
    'date_naissance',
    'telephone',
    'cin',
    ];

  public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(document::class);
}
```

`CandidatController`

```
  public function show()
   {
    $candidat = candidat::all();
    return view('candidat.liste', compact('candidat'));

}
```

`candidat/liste`:

```
  @foreach($candidat as $key => $data)
 {....
  {{$data->document->doc}} #this provoked the error
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, first you called your method `documents`, not `document`... Second, `documents` would return a Collection, so you'd have to do `foreach($data->documents as $document)` before you could access `$document->doc`.

Comment: @TimLewis you're my savior thank you

Comment: Happy to help as always  Few more notes, Model names are `StudlyCase`, so `Document` and `Candidat`, you don't need to specify `'candidat_id'` as the 2nd param of `belongsTo()` if the model name matches the relationship (`Candidat` and `candiat()` match), and lastly, include "Eager Loading" to avoid slowdown, replace `candidat::all()` with `Candidat::with('documents')->get()`; same end result, much faster!

Comment: @TimLewis got it, thank you